# Weblogic deployment failing with error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when ear build in a machine, Same code is working when build using other machine

Tags: java, maven, classloader, weblogic12g

Java application built using maven working in one machine but failing withother machine having same configuration.

Java - jdk1.8.0_331
Weblogic - 12.2.1.4.0
Maven - 3.6.0

When ear is built in Machine1 causing the below error and same code built in another machine deployment is successful and web application is up and running.
<Servlet: "Jersey" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/api/".
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;

Compared both the ear structures and find no differences.
Seems that the issue is with classloading, but not able to find the root cause of the issue.

Tried updating the package in weblogic-application.xml but issue not resolved

```
<prefer-application-packages>
<package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
 </prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: Have you considered setting up a build server?

Comment: If you build the ear with different machines with the same toolchain the result should be quite the same. If the result differs there are differences in the toolchain. You should double check if maven/java version are really the same. If it matches you could diff the ears to find what's the difference between both ears.

Comment: The maven and java versions are same and there are no differences in the generated ear . I have compared both the ears.

Comment: I tried copying the working ear from one machine to another machine . Even then the same issue occurring. Need pointers on the issue.